# Антоним мобильной версии сайта

Tags: выбор-слов, антонимы

Какой антоним мобильной версии сайта? Стационарная (как в педивикии)?

Answer (score 1):

Обычно говорят "десктопная версия".

Answer (score 1):

Стационарная или декстопная, все верно.

Comment: Стационарная как-то не так звучит - нотбук же мобильный? А на большом планшете какая показывается, кстати?

Comment: Фраза «мобильная версия» подразумевается для телефонов и планшетов, а стационарная или декстопная — для компьютеров.